# Insert column in data frame with duplicated axis

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What would be the workaround (or the more tidy way) to insert a column in a pandas dataframe where some indices are duplicated?

For example, having the following dataframe:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({ 0: (1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4),
                    1: (51, 51, 74, 29, 39, 3, 14, 16),
                    2: pd.Categorical(['R', 'R', 'R', 'R', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F']) })
df1 = df1.set_index([0])
df1
    1  2
0       
1  51  R
2  51  R
3  74  R
4  29  R
1  39  F
2   3  F
3  14  F
4  16  F
```

how can I insert the column `foo` from `df2` (below) in df1?

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({ 0: (1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 4),
                    'foo': (5, 5, 7, 2, 3, 1, 1),
                    2: pd.Categorical(['R', 'R', 'R', 'R', 'F', 'F', 'F']) })
df2 = df2.set_index([0])
df2
   foo  2
0        
1    5  R
2    5  R
3    7  R
4    2  R
1    3  F
3    1  F
4    1  F
```

Note that the index `2` is missing from category `F`.

I would like the result to be something like:

```
    1  foo  2
0            
1  51    5  R
2  51    5  R
3  74    7  R
4  29    2  R
1  39    3  F
2   3  NaN  F
3  14    1  F
4  16    1  F
```

I tried the DataFrame.insert method but am getting

```
df1.insert(2, 'FOO', df2['foo'])
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The index and column *2* uniquely define a row on both data frames, you can do a join on the two columns (after resetting the index):

```
df1.reset_index().merge(df2.reset_index(), how='left', on=[0,2]).set_index([0])

#    1  2   foo
#0          
#1  51  R   5.0
#2  51  R   5.0
#3  74  R   7.0
#4  29  R   2.0
#1  39  F   3.0
#2  3   F   NaN
#3  14  F   1.0
#4  16  F   1.0
```

Comment: I accepted this answer because it fits nicely with whatI have already in the code, but the answers from LateCoder and A.Kot would also work

Answer (score 1):

You're very close...

As you already know based on your question, you can't do this for reasons clearly stated in the error, because you have a repeated index. If you must have column '0' as the index, then don't set it as the index before your merge, set it after:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({ 0: (1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4),
                1: (51, 51, 74, 29, 39, 3, 14, 16),
                2: pd.Categorical(['R', 'R', 'R', 'R', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F']) })
df2 = pd.DataFrame({ 0: (1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 4),
                'foo': (5, 5, 7, 2, 3, 1, 1),
                2: pd.Categorical(['R', 'R', 'R', 'R', 'F', 'F', 'F']) })
df = df1.merge(df2, how='left')

df.set_index([0])
```

Comment: There's a quote missing on how='left'

Comment: @PedroA Thanks mate.

Answer (score 1):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({ 0: (1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4),
                1: (51, 51, 74, 29, 39, 3, 14, 16),
                2: pd.Categorical(['R', 'R', 'R', 'R', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F']) })
df2 = pd.DataFrame({ 0: (1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 4),
                'foo': (5, 5, 7, 2, 3, 1, 1),
                2: pd.Categorical(['R', 'R', 'R', 'R', 'F', 'F', 'F']) })
df1 = df1.set_index([0, 2])
df2 = df2.set_index([0, 2])
df1.join(df2, how='left').reset_index(level=2)
   2   1  foo
0
1  R  51  5.0
2  R  51  5.0
3  R  74  7.0
4  R  29  2.0
1  F  39  3.0
2  F   3  NaN
3  F  14  1.0
4  F  16  1.0
```